# Python ftplib file open() TypeError

Tags: python, ftp, typeerror, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file to an ftp server with python using the ftplib.

This is what i have:

```
def ftp(cmd):

    cmd = cmd.split(' ')
    try: cmd[3]
    except: return 'host user password file (ftpdir)'
    try: session = ftplib.FTP(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2])
    except: return 'wrong credentials/host'
    try: file = open(cmd[3], 'rb')
    except: return 'unable to reach file'
    try: cmd[4]
    except: pass
    else: 
        if cmd[4] !='':
            ftplib.FTP.cwd(ftpdir)
    name = file.split('\\')[-1]
    session.storbinary('STOR ' + name, file)     # send the file
    file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
    session.quit()
```

I give the function a command in the form of 'host user password file ftpdir' where ftpdir is not required. The error I get is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  ...some lines of referring...

  File "C:\somedir\somefile.py", line 155, in ftp
    file = open(cmd[3],'rb')
TypeError: open() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

If i try the command "file = open(cmd[3], 'rb')" with a given 'cmd' as entry in a python shell it works fine.

Comment: What do your import statements look like? To me, it looks like the definition of the `open` function is being overwritten.

Comment: Is your code really the way you've included it? It seems like that exception should be eaten by the `try`/`except` block around the `open` call (which is one reason that a bare `except` is a bad idea!).

Comment: Oh god, I see it now. I defined another function with open... Thank you @frb . Sorry about that, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is now answered. The problem was that I defined another function open(arg) which took exactely one argument. After changing the name of that function, everything worked fine.

Thank you for your time everyone who read this.